# Google custom site search engine, how to create product xml feed

Tags: xml, search, feed

I just purchased a [business edition of google custom search engine](https://www.google.com/cse/compare) so I can search through  my online shop and display the results with the product schema.

Here's what my goal is, I want my search results to be shown with the **title**, **price**, **description** and **thumbnail**.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/snippets

I've been searching all over the web now trying to find out how i can customize the results to be shown as products, I read that i need a `xml` feed, but I'm not a `xml` programmer, so can anyone help me with this, or is there any tutorial I can follow to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use w3schools to learn about xml.
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp
If you want automatic generation of feed for your website you can use wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 of Google custom search does not allow for advanced customisation.

Look out for V1 if you want to display an Image, Description, Link or whatever else is marked up via rich snippets on your website.

See this [link for more information](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/rendering).